# Regex expression to remove <version> tag

Tags: regex, grep

I have text coming out from grep cmd:

```
<version>abc</version>
```

What would be right regex to filter out version tags?

```
grep version\> | grep **regex**
```

Comment: Like `</?version\s*/?>` you mean ?

Comment: @sln I'm doing grep version\> | sed 's/<[^>]*>//g'
but i'm getting white-space with value:     abc

Comment: It looks like  you're deleting the html there `s///g` isn't that what you want ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `awk` may do:

```
echo "<version>abc</version>" | awk -F"[<>]" '{print $3}'
abc
```

Setting field separator to `<` and `>`, then print third field.